# How to find post with broken image link and delete that post

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have some post in my autoblog that by cronjob mistake the feautured image being deleted.
how to find all of that post (**post with broken image link**) and delete all of it or set the default image if the featured image is missing without searching one by one through thousand of post.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to crawl your website and **find broken links and images** on your website is this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-checker

Comment: already try but come up empty, i try to learn to do that without plugin, want to learn how to use wordpress plug-in free.

Comment: Then you can use external tools or apps like screamingfrog.
https://validator.w3.org/checklink
https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/broken-link-checker/

Comment: i need to know how to do this via simple php script in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Broken Link Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/) plugin. It detects broken links and images. It also fixes them with redirects. So, you don't have to search one by one through thousands of posts and delete the broken ones.

Comment: already try but come up empty, i try to learn to do that without plugin, want to learn how to use wordpress plug-in free.